# Не отправляется письмо SmtpClient (await/async/wait())

Tags: c#, асинхронность, smtp, task, async-await

Друзья привет, есть 2 метода. Верхний отвечает за отправку сообщения, второй за формирование сообщения. В данном виде они не работают, при этом в логи не падает ошибка, а падает сообщение, что письмо ушло, на сервер смтп при этом ничего не приходило.

Нашел как заставить это работать. Надо либо в первом методе `await client.SendMailAsync(message);` заменить на `client.SendMailAsync(message).Wait();` либо во втором методе заменить `await SendMailAsync(message, login, password);` на `SendMailAsync(message, login, password).Wait();`

```
public static async Task SendMailAsync(MailMessage message, string login = null, string password = null, int timeout = 10000)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            if (login != null && password != null)
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
            client.Timeout = timeout;
            await client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

Метод второй

```
public static async void SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body = "", string login = null, string password = null, bool isHtml = true)
    {
        if (!Parameters.MainSettings.ServiceEmail)
            return;

        try
        {
            var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = isHtml };
            await SendMailAsync(message, login, password);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Т.Е вроде проблема решена, но мне хотелось бы узнать почему так происходит, вроде должны в этом коде работать одинаково await и Wait(); Вроде прочитал разницу между асинхронными операциями и тасками, но решение моего вопроса мне это не подсказало.

Comment: Без ассинхронности то работает?

Comment: `async SendMailAsync(message, login, password);` опечатка?

Comment: Тип приложения какой? Консоль?

Comment: `вроде должны в этом коде работать одинаково await и Wait();` не вроде, а должны. Только второй вам поток заблочит и дедлок может вызвать. Что за класс `SmtpClient`, из какой библиотеки? Или нативный из дотнета? Если да, то он устарел и не рекомендуется к использованию.

Comment: [SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134519/12888024)

Comment: @aepot коммент поставлен когда-то в моно, и разошёлся по всем системам случайно. SmtpClient отлично работает. We - это ментейнер моно :)

Comment: @aepot потом кто-то увидел этот ворнинг, затянул в правило код анализа и заверте.

Comment: Есть шанс что вы на самом верху не написали await, и у вас просто не дожидается реальной отправки письма. Добавьте трассировку - напишите что-нибудь в лог после await SendMailAsync и проверьте что он до конца отрабатывает

Comment: @PashaPash это не отменяет того что у клиента ужастная начинка, и лучше его не использовать. И автор его диспозит, чего делать не следует, иначе будет фейлиться отправка в многопоточке.

Comment: @aepot вот вы говорите ужасная, а есть ревью от автора mailkit, где он говорит что там все норм. Кому верить…

Comment: @aepot можно подробнее про проблему с диспоузом?

Comment: @PashaPash https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/MailKit-MimeKit-Official/

Comment: @aepot вы не поверите, но https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2986. Краткий пересказ - из-за бага генератора документации в нее были включены все атрибуты для всех платформ, включая Mono (Xamarin), и это разнесли по всем новостям (The documentation for SmtpClient now reads, “Obsolete()."). Текущий статус Obsolete расписан в https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netframework-4.7#remarks.

Comment: @aepot коротко - The SmtpClient class is obsolete in Xamarin. Потому что ментейнер ксамарина (он же второй человек по коммитам в mailkit) взял и поставил там этот атрибут. Реально нет никакого нормально justification почему SmtpClient не рекомендуется. "poorly designed (по мнению одного человека, коммитавшего в mailkit"). "doesn't support many modern protocols" - без конкретного списка этих самых modern. Поверьте, я в теме, и ссылка на статью какого-то "аналитика" который заметил атрибут и наврал в новости не проверяя - это не аргумент ни разу :)

Comment: @Петян - скорее всего где-то выше по коду вы не делаете await SendMail. Поставьте трассировку после async SendMailAsync и проверьте что вы реально доходите до конца отправки. Иначе есть шанс что ваш код просто не отправляет реально письмо потому что просто не дожидается где-то в середине процесса отправки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132200/discussion-between-pashapash-and-aepot).

Comment: @Blackmeser
 да, если убрать асинхронность то отрабатывает как надо

Comment: @aepot тип приложения консоль.

Comment: @PashaPash
все перепроверил. awaitы написал. Я думал может есть все таки разница между await и wait(). Но раз разницы нет, перепроверю еще раз

Comment: @Петян ну тогда я знаю, в чем дело. Используйте спокойно Wait(), либо нужен однопоточный контекст синхронизации. Если хотите, покажу пример с контекстом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Сразу после отправки консольное приложение закрывалось. Т.К мы не ждали что все письма уйдут, приложение закрывалось до того, как уходили все письма. Добавил после отправки каждого сообщения Thread.Sleep() и все сообщения доставляются. Всем спасибо

Comment: Так не правильно, вам нужно Task.Wait

Comment: Убрать using у SmtpClient пробовали? По идее должно работать и без слипа. Sleep может не всегда сработать, так как неизвестно, сколько надо времени на отправку. В любом случае, это костыль, а не решение, к тому же очень ненадежный.

Comment: @Blackmeser если по-настоящему запариться, то вот решение https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/ потому что этот клиент видимо пилился в условиях ui контекста винформ. А здесь консоль, нет контекста. Но мне лень пилить ответ, если только автору это реально надо, тогда напишу.